# changes in Visual effects in windows 7 by changing registries are being applied but not showing in the performance options

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, visual-effects

I have disabled all the visual effects of windows 7 by changing registries as per instructions that I saw on this page: 
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1908-visual-effects-settings-change.html?filter
The changes to the visual effects are being applied after restarting my pc but are not being reflected in the performance options in the visual tab. i.e. all of the visual effects should be shown as disabled.

How can I make the changes to the visual effects that I have applied in the registry show up as disabled in system properties-> performance options->visual effects tab.

Answer (score 1):

In the Registry navigate to

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

If the "System" key doesn't exist create a Right-Click and select New > Key and name it "System". Then right-click and select New > String Value and name it "SetVisualStyle" and leave it empty. Then logoff and log back on and you should have all visual effects disabled.

Comment: Zalmy, the visual effects are being disabled but still when i open the performance options in system properties and navigate to the visual effects tab, all effects are shown as enabled but infact they are not.

Comment: This is because the registry key enables avgroup policy which disables visual efects and overrides the users settings.

Comment: thank u zalmy for your answer. also can u tell if i want 2 or 3 visual effects enabled out of all, then what will be the method to do it. and also if those registry changes can be reflected in the system properties-> performance options->visual effects tab.